# Getting logout issue after clicked on link from email

Tags: php, html, logout

I am getting the issue in log out. I have change_password link on my email and when I clicked on the link, the page should be redirected on change_password.php but currently page is redirecting on Index.php because of added logout code. Logout code is working on my all pages except change_passwords.php.Would you help me out in this?

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/changepassword.php?key=$id">change password</a>
```

Change_password.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username1'])) { //if not yet logged in
       header("Location: login.php");// send to login page
       exit;
    }
    include('db/connection.php');

/*
rest of code
*/
```

Comment: have you tried using the whole path to your login script?

Comment: and please check also if your session cache is cleared properly and no userdata is stored anymore after logout

Comment: Yes, I tried my whole path but I don't know still page is redirecting on index

Comment: Do you have any other code inside Change_password.php which may redirect to index.php?  Open developer console on Network Tab, after that click on the "change password" and see if it hits the desirable link - if yes - then something is redirecting the user to index.php

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Antonis, NO I don't have another code to redirect

Comment: have you checked if the `header()`-Command gets executed? I.e. with replacing the line with a simple `echo` or something like this.

Comment: Is the <a href> inside html or php tags? If it is html you will have to replace $id with <?php echo $id; ?>

Comment: $email_body="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>HTML email</title></head>
<body>
<p>Set your password<a href='http://www.domain.com/changepassword.php?user_id=$User_id1'> here </a></p>
</body>
</html>";

Comment: Mr.Antonis, I added my link code.It is in php tags

Comment: Mr.Andy, Can you help me with example?

Comment: @Hybreeder When it comes to your email, does it have the correct url link?

Comment: why don't you test for empty though?
 if(!isset($_SESSION['username1']) && empty[$_SESSION['username1'])

Comment: Not enough information. What has the logout process got to do with a change password process

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Mr.Riggs, I have one page called as change_password.php. If any user entered the direct path in URL like domain.com/change_password.php then the page should be redirected on index.php.

Comment: User can access that page only from link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. I don't know it's correct or not but it is working for me.

```
<a href='http://www.domain.in/changepassword.php?user_id=$User_id1'>
```

above link I get user id from URL using $_GET['user_id'] and added in session

```
$_SESSION['get_id']=$_GET['user_id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['get_id'])) { //if not yet logged in
   header("Location: login.php");// send to login page
   exit;
}
```

Please assist me more secure and reliable